# how to generate string const in z3 through java-api

Tags: java, z3

How can I generate string const in z3 through java-api? For integer, there are `ctx.mkInt(int a)` generate an IntExpr with value a and `ctx.mkIntConst("a")` generate an IntExpr with name "a". However, for string, I can only find `ctx.mkString("a")`, which is just a SeqExpr with value "a" similar as ctx.mkInt. So what I want is something like `ctx.mkStringConst("a")` but there is no such function.

I find in python api, what I want is is simply `str = String("a")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
String variable_name="foo";
Expr variable = context.mkConst(context.mkSymbol(variable_name), context.mkStringSort());
```